# "BeforeClose" function with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements

Is there a way to prevent Excel from closing if cell B34 > 0 **and** J34 = 0?

If they leave B34 alone then J34 doesn't need to be filled in and the workbook can close.
If they enter data into B34 we need info in J34 as well.

Something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    If Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B34").Value > "" and _
           Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B34").Value = "" Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "Please fill in the total % in cell J34"
   End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ThisWorkbook object:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
 
    If ws.Range("B34").Value <> "" And ws.Range("J34").Value = "" Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "Please fill in the total % in cell J34"
    End If
 
End Sub
```